# Unix program for random image generator

Tags: linux, html, programming

I want to create a basic program in Unix that would display in HTML a random photo from a group of photos I selected and each time it is generated a different one would be displayed, hence random.

Example: Dog breeds and each time you ran the program an HTML page would display an image of a random dog breed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because this is about setting up a website, and doesn't belong in its current form on any of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your filenames don't have embedded newlines:

```
find /some/dir -type f -name '*.jpg' | shuf | head -1
```

There are much better ways to do it from a web server though.